# how to "hang" file with the uso of cycle for

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop, cycle

I started now with the bash script and I'm trying to make a for loop that uses an array where there are the arguments passed to the script (2 or more files) trying to "hang" with the ">>" command, the first ones "n-1" files passed as argument to the last file (n) , writing the input files in the order from right to left

for example :

```
myscript.sh file1 file2 file3 file4
```

`file4` will contain in sequence `file3 file2 file1`

```
arr=($@)
j=$#-1
    for i in { j-1..0..1 }

  do 
         cat arr[i] >> $[j]

          done
```

**I tried to do it this way but it doesn't work, can someone help me?**

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "hang"?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
n=$#
for i in $(seq $((n - 1)) -1 1) ; do
  cat ${@:$i:1} >> ${@:$n:1}
done
```

Explanation:

1. `seq $((n - 1)) -1 1` generates the numbers from `$n - 1` to `1` in reverse order.
2. `${@:$i:1}` gives the element `$i` of the array of the arguments of the script.

Or, without `seq`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
n=$#
for ((i = n - 1; i; i--)) ; do
  echo "cat ${@:$i:1} >> ${@:$n:1}"
done
```

Or even shorter, with a while loop instead of a for loop, and maybe off topic for this reason:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
i=${#}
while ((--i)) ; do
  echo "cat ${@:$i:1} >> ${@:$#:1}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what about "hang", but this concatenates the first files to the last filename

```
cat "${@:0:$#}" > "${@: -1:1}"
```

this is [slicing](https://ngelinux.com/brief-explanation-string-and-array-slicing-in-bash-shell-linux/) the the arguments.

Comment: Very nice shot, but the PO needs to have the files concatenated in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You could print all arguments except the last one on separate lines, reverse the files order and then cat all of them into the file that is the last argument:

```
printf "%s\n" "${@:1:$#-1}" | tac | xargs cat > "${@: -1}"
```

The same using zero as the stream separator:

```
printf "%s\0" "${@:1:$#-1}" | tac -s '' | xargs -0 cat > "${@: -1}"
```

It would be very advisable to protect against the count of arguments less then 2, because when `$# = 0` then `${@: -1}` will be `$0`. Then `$0` could be your shell with ex full path like `/bin/bash`, so `>` could overwrite your shell executable file!

So do:

```
if (($# >= 2)); then printf "%s\0" "${@:1:$#-1}" | tac -s '' | xargs -0 cat > "${@: -1}"; fi
```